# ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception - doFilter and invokeDelegate repeated

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, web-config, servlet-filters

I am using spring boot (2.0.4.RELEASE), spring (5.0.6.RELEASE) AND Spring security version (5.0.4.RELEASE). Below is my code snippet. Application is started successfully. But when I am trying to hit any API, below exception occurs. Thanks in advance for help.

**Exception in postman:**

```
    "timestamp": "2020-05-19T16:20:28.456+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/order/fulfillment/services/tasks/1280907"
}
```

**Exception in application:**

```
2020-05-19 23:04:20,619 [INFO] [order-fulfillment] [http-nio-8082-exec-1] [o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2020-05-19 23:04:20,688 [INFO] [order-fulfillment] [http-nio-8082-exec-1] [o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 69 ms
2020-05-19 23:04:20,884 [ERROR] [order-fulfillment] [http-nio-8082-exec-1] [o.s.c.s.i.w.ExceptionLoggingFilter] - Uncaught exception thrown
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
```

**Code Snippet**

1. WebConfigSecurity.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Order(1000)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final CommonLogger LOGGER = CommonLoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    //@Value("${order.fulfillment.security.unsecured}")
    private String[] unSecuredUrls = "/actuator/*,/actuator/{\\d+},/api-docs,/swagger-resources/**,/swagger-ui.html,/webjars/**,/camunda/*,/camunda/**,/engine-rest/*,/engine-rest/**,/cloudfoundryapplication/*,/cloudfoundryapplication/{\\d+}".split(",");

    private String loginUrl = "https://dtl.home.com";
    private String logoutUrl = "https://dtl.home.com";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Web Security Config");
        LOGGER.info(new CommonLogUtil.Builder()
                .withMessage("The unSecuredUrls " + Arrays.toString(unSecuredUrls))
                .withMethodName(CONFIGURE_METHOD)
                .build().toString());

        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().disable();
        http.headers().cacheControl(); // Disable browser caching server content

        http.addFilterBefore(customPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(unSecuredUrls).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);
        http.formLogin().loginPage(loginUrl);
        http.logout().invalidateHttpSession(true);
        http.logout().clearAuthentication(true);
        http.logout().logoutUrl(logoutUrl);

        super.configure(http);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        //HTTP settings bug with Spring security since 1.5.9 only seems to affect HTTP - fo my need that is local desktop and dev cloud
        //for time being work around seems to be to use default http settings for
        //Allows customizing the HttpFirewall. The default is StrictHttpFirewall.
        Set<String> activeProfiles = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("local")); //prismRequestHelper.onApplicationReadyEvent();
        Set<String> containsAny = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(LOCAL.getValue(), DEV.getValue()));
        if (CollectionUtils.containsAny(activeProfiles, containsAny)) {
            super.configure(web);
            try {
                web.httpFirewall(defaultHttpFirewall());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").anyRequest();
    }

    @Bean
    //this is just a need for http - local/dev cloud
    public HttpFirewall defaultHttpFirewall() {
        DefaultHttpFirewall firewall = new DefaultHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        return firewall;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter customPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("in customPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter");
        CustomPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter customPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter = new CustomPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter();
        customPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return customPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

2. CustomPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java

```
public class CustomPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    private static final CommonLogger LOGGER = CommonLoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);

    /**
     * Override to extract the principal information from the current request.
     *
     * @param httpServletRequest
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        Enumeration headerNames = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();
        List<String> headerList = Collections.list(headerNames);
        if (headerList.contains(OrderFulfillmentConstants.HTTP_HEADER_SYNAPSE_TARGET_TAG)) {
            OrderFulfillmentServiceUtil.setSynapseTag(httpServletRequest.getHeader(OrderFulfillmentConstants.HTTP_HEADER_SYNAPSE_TARGET_TAG));
        } else {
            OrderFulfillmentServiceUtil.setSynapseTag(null);
        }
        return "dummy";
    }

    /**
     * Override to extract the credentials (if applicable) from the current request.
     * Should not return null for a valid principal, though some implementations may
     * return a dummy value.
     *
     * @param httpServletRequest
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return "dummy";
    }
}
```